# Running functions onclick. All buttons being clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have many buttons that have `class="clearSelect"`. I want these buttons the execute a function onclick. I am new to javascript and not quite sure why this is occurring but I think my functions are being executed instead of only executing `onclick`

The code below is what is calling all my other functions causing every button to be clicked.

code:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("clearSelect");  // objects with class="clearSelect"

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    // button.addEventListener("onclick", clearOrSelectAll(button.id));
    button.onclick = clearOrSelectAll(button.id);
}
```

These are the functions being called:

```
function clearOrSelectAll(btn) {
    var cleartab = clearButtonSet[btn];
    var selecttab = selectButtonSet[btn];
    // console.log("clicked!");
    if (cleartab != null) {
        getOSList(cleartab, false);
    } else {
        getOSList(selecttab, true);
    }
}

function getOSList(tabVal, fate) {
    var configTab = document.getElementById(tabVal);
    var browserList = configTab.getElementsByClassName("browser_list");
    // var idObjs = browserList.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var h = 0; h < browserList.length; h++) {
        var idObjs = browserList[h].getElementsByTagName("li");
        // console.log(h);
        // console.log(idObjs);
        // select all
        if (fate) {
            for (var i = 0; i < idObjs.length; i++) {
                if (configs[idObjs[i].id] == null) {
                    idObjs[i].className = "selected";
                    configs[idObjs[i].id] = config_dictionary[idObjs[i].id];
                }
            }
        // clear all
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < idObjs.length; j++) {
                if (configs[idObjs[j].id] == null) {
                    idObjs[j].className = "unselected";
                    delete configs[idObjs[j].id];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `button.onclick = function() { clearOrSelectAll(button.id); }`

Comment: @Danijel thank you for the input! much appreciated! However, now my functions do not work =/

Answer (score 2):

@Christopher was very close, but `button.id` should be `this.id`.

```
button.onclick = function() {
  clearOrSelectAll(this.id);
}
```

The reason `button.id` doesn't work can be demonstrated with this code:

```js
var buttons= document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  button.onclick = function() {
    alert(button.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="B1">Button 1</button>
<button id="B2">Button 2</button>
<button id="B3">Button 3</button>
```

Each button returns "B3," because that's the last object that the variable `button` is assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop when you attach the event to all of the buttons, you are calling the clearOrSelectAll function. You probably want to wrap it in an anonymous function to make sure it's only called when the event is fired.

```js
// Non-ideal solution: see edit
button.onclick = function() {
    clearOrSelectAll(button.id);
}
```

**EDIT:** It has been pointed out that the 'this' context variable will point to the element in question when an event handler is attached by means of the onclick property, or the addEventListener method. As such it would probably be cleaner (and easier to read) if you were to reference that instead of using 'button' as a closure and count on javascript engines to not optimize your loop too heavily (as that would mess with the value of 'button' at the time that the event is called.

```js
button.onclick = function() {
    clearOrSelectAll(this.id);
};
```

Comment: You may need to change button.id to this.id.

Comment: @RickHitchcock worked! If you reply with a answer I will gladly accept

Comment: The button variable should be able to pull from the for loop (taking the form of a closure), as the context in which the function was defined should stick around. Additionally, since the event is not being attached with jQuery, I don't think that 'this' would point to the element. I think it would point to the window. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Christopher I have `$(document).ready(function() {` at the beginning of my program. Maybe I should have mentioned that in the beginning

Comment: `this` refers to objects within their event handlers.  jQuery's `$(this)` works similarly, in order to behave similarly to JavaScript.

Comment: A quick look through MDN confirms that you are correct. I was confusing  the context considerations for the javascript onclick property with the html onclick attribute (yucky inline event handlers...). I will update my answer accordingly.